# movie2avi producing axes at 45 degree angles

Tags: matlab

I used M(i) = getframe; within my loop to capture each frame of my figure, and running movie(M) works perfectly.

But then I tried

```
movie2avi(M, 'excav_sim.avi', 'compression', 'None');
```

and instead of displaying my axes squarely, they have one axis at a 45 degree angle, with everything else skewed accordingly.  What can I do (any movie option will work, but online sources haven't helped so far).

Comment: I've seen this behavior too, I never really found a solution other than "switch to windows", so...Favorited :)

Comment: +1 I have see this problem too.

Comment: If you can use something other than an AVI as the container format (and assuming that the issue is with `movie2avi` rather than `getframe`), you might try my [QTWriter](http://horchler.github.io/QTWriter/) function that allows you to export lossy and lossless QuickTime movies in a few basic formats (codecs) that work well with Matlab content. QTWriter works very similarly to Matlab's [`VideoWriter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriterclass.html).